# Is this wavelet transform implementation correct?

Tags: python, fft, wavelet, haar-wavelet, wavelet-transform

I am searching for alternatives to the FFT to create a spectrogram analyser in python. I heard that the wavelet transform is faster and provides better time accuracy than the short time FFT. I went in this wikipedia article that features the Haar wavelet transform implementation in Java:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform#Code_example

I brutally converted it to python but I have no idea if the values I'm getting are correct. Can someone confirm?

```
from math import *

N = 8
res = [sin(k) for k in xrange(N)]

for k in xrange(N):
    print res[k]

print

def discreteHaarWaveletTransform(x):
    N = len(x)
    output = [0.0]*N

    length = N >> 1
    while True:
        for i in xrange(0,length):
            summ = x[i * 2] + x[i * 2 + 1]
            difference = x[i * 2] - x[i * 2 + 1]
            output[i] = summ
            output[length + i] = difference

        if length == 1:
            return output

        #Swap arrays to do next iteration
        #System.arraycopy(output, 0, x, 0, length << 1)
        x = output[:length << 1]

        length >>= 1


res = discreteHaarWaveletTransform(res)

for k in xrange(N):
    print res[k]
```

Result:

```
0.0
0.841470984808
0.909297426826
0.14112000806
-0.756802495308
-0.958924274663
-0.279415498199
0.656986598719

0.553732750242
3.23004408914
-0.208946450078
-2.09329787049
-0.841470984808
0.768177418766
0.202121779355
-0.936402096918
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't find anything wrong. You can also check it by comparing your result to the result from [Pywavelet package](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/). There is also an [example](http://jseabold.net/blog/2012/02/23/wavelet-regression-in-python/) on the implementation of haar wavelet with Pywavelet.